# how do i append a string to a slice inside a slice?

Tags: arrays, loops, go, slice

```
 sos := make([][]string,3)

ss := [["name","place","thing"],["name","place","thing"],["name","place","thing"]]
```

let sos be [["name","name"],["place","place"],["thing","thing"]
how can i **append** the name,place and thing fields?***preferably using a for loop from ss to sos?***

```
 for i:=0;i<len(sos);i++ {
    sos[i] = append(sos[i],ss[0])
    }
```

the above for loop can append only the first variable i.e "name" from ss to sos,how can i append the rest of the variables too?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What exactly do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you want to do this ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    sos := make([][]string, 3)

    ss := [][]string{ []string{"name", "place", "thing"}, []string{"name", "place", "thing"}, []string{"name", "place", "thing"} }


    for i := range ss {
        for j := range ss[i] {
            sos[i] = append(sos[i], ss[j][i])
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(sos)
}
```

output:

[[name name name] [place place place] [thing thing thing]]

[Go playGround](https://play.golang.org/p/jn5x8FqjVsU)

Thanks.